# Should I tell my Team Leader that I've been diagnosed with ADHD?

Tags: health, mental-health

I received an ADHD diagnosis today from a psychiatrist.

I'm not sure what I'm doing with this knowledge at the moment. Certainly, I'll be taking the medication I've been provided, and then will be checking back with they psychiatrist to see how it's going. I'll also been looking at ADHD support groups etc.

The other relevant information is that I've been on performance management as a result of depressive issues/lack of engagement with work. So this team leader is aware of on going mental issues.

Answer (score 15):

Under normal circumstances I'd say no, do not tell him. Everybody has issues and it's not your team leaders job to manage or handle them, so there is nothing to gain from him knowing.

In your situation however, with your team leader aware of the performance issues you have, you should tell him. Because this shows that you are also aware of the problems *and you are actively working on solving them*. Regardless of actual diagnosis, getting help for your problems is a huge step in the right direction.

Even if you fail whatever performance plan he set up, knowing you are indeed working on it might grant you another chance. Maybe you can even get an improved plan more tailored to your specific situation. For example medication for chronic issues is rarely spot on the first time. So if you are trying different medication or dosage, you could adjust your work load accordingly. Maybe not have customer meetings the day this changes so you can adjust to the changes before you are in situations where you must perform the first time and cannot make up for suboptimal performance through overtime.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a different approach to nvoigt's answer, even though it's a good answer and many points I agree with :)

I would recommend that if you feel that there was any way that your ADHD would impact on your ability to do your job, you need to make your boss aware as soon as possible.  As nvoigt said, you are getting treatment and it's under control, but by letting them know about it, they have a better understanding if you have any bad days.

Again, since you are already affected in your job, then telling them is especially important, but even if it were a *potential* problem, I would still say you should inform them.

Comment: I'm not sure about this.  If it *is* impacting the job, then yes tell the manager.  If it is *not current* impacting the job then health issues, imho, should be kept private.  There's no reason to raise a potential red flag when no problem exists.

Comment: @Notme My rationale is that it can be managed more effectively _from a manager's viewpoint_ to understand any potential personal issues with your team.  It means that if something happens unexpectedly (it's under control _now_, but things sometimes change), then you can be compassionate towards the reasons for any impact it may have.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, but tactfully**. It can be a pro, make use of that.

I'd like to start off with: **The fact that you've got this diagnosis doesn't suddenly change you!** You allready had this, it's "just confirmed". There's nothing bad in this. *At worst* this doesn't change a thing. But from this point on you can take advantage of it, AD(H)D is not a disease!

I have a form of ADD (for people less informed; ADD is mentally about the same, but physically less of the **H**yper), which I found out about beginning of this year (in restrospect, I have this much longer, just didn't actively know).
I read a book called (translated) "**Hooray, I've got ADHD!**". This title might strike as a bit odd, but it has a perfect mindset about the topic.
**AD(H)D is not a disease, it's a different/unique mindset.**

You (can) think differently, which is, if properly controlled, a pro and not a con!
There are advantages of AD(H)D:

- I can go into hyperfocus, an 'extreme' state of concentration, for a certain amount of time, which can be extremely usefull when a critical bug needs to be fixed 5 minutes ago. Does tire me out though.
- I tend to think a bit different, I can come up with solutions which others can't
- My mind is very busy, I can switch between different subjects really fast

The main con of ADD the the concentration problem, I can't concentrate a full day. You'll have to find small functional break (clean some stuff, etc etc) which doesn't require a lot of thinking

I started out with highlighting the pro's of it to my employer, hinting "I can recognise myself in that theory". My employer now actually sees it as a pro.

**If other people have suggestions on how AD(H)D can be a pro, feel free to add those to this answer!*

Answer (score 2):

> Should I tell my Team Leader that I've been diagnosed with ADHD?

**Yes.**

Your team lead already knows that you have some issues. And you have indicated that you are on "performance management" (I'll assume that is the same thing as a formal Performance Plan).

Now is your chance to tell your team lead about the possible reasons behind your performance issues, and talk about the plan going forward to correct them now that you have a formal diagnosis.

As you learn more about your medications and support group work, share them with your team lead as well (particularly if there may be side-effects evident in the workplace, or if you need to alter your work schedule to accommodate appointments or support group sessions).

It must feel great to finally have this formal diagnosis completed! Share that feelings with your team lead, and find ways to work together to improve your performance.